# Google Chromebook API usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working with a Chromebook API that is hosted on google.  It passes credentials from the computer SSO session to the user session, see here: [Advanced Inregration for SAML SSO](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/advanced-integration-for-saml-sso-on-chrome-devices)

My SAML IDP works fine and the sessions authenticate but I need to pass this information to the user session.  This API does just that.

There's basically very little documentation out there for this API.  What I'm not understanding are the following calls:

```
initialize(callback)
add(details,callback)
complete(details,callback)
```

I'm good with the "details" part of the call, but I'm not sure what the callback functions are supposed to be doing or providing.  How can I figure out what the callback functions are supposed to do in a javascript library?  Or am I just plain stuck without being provided this information?

Comment: If you use a callback such as `(...args) => console.log(args)`, you can figure out what the callbacks arguments are

Comment: I see what you are getting at, but I'm not an excellent javascript person (although I have a feeling I will be in a month or so).  Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Replace "callback" in your code with the code I just gave you.